# why "kubectl exec -it" cannot login etcd pod

Tags: kubernetes

when I exec `# kubectl -n kube-system exec -it etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.160 sh`

It returns an error:`error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("etcd")`

But I can login to the container by `docker exec`

The etcd's health is ok.

```
# /tmp/etcdctl --endpoints=https://10.128.128.160:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/chamc-ctrl/pki/etcd/ca.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/chamc-ctrl/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key  --cert=/etc/kubernetes/chamc-ctrl/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt endpoint  health --cluster
https://10.128.128.160:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 7.347977ms
https://10.128.128.161:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 10.045414ms
https://10.128.128.162:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 10.46153ms
```

This makes me confused.

Before I try to login etcd pod, I exec `kubectl logs -f etcd_pod`, but there are no errors.

Thanks for your help~

There are some infos:

PS:There are three pods of etcd,after I restart one of them I can login by 'kubectl exec '

-> versions:

```
root@cust92-qzctrl-master-jd-qz-vm1:~# `kubelet --version`
Kubernetes v1.13.12-netease
[root@gd-dpnsf03 kubelet]# `kubectl version`
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.12", GitCommit:"a8b52209ee172232b6db7a6e0ce2adc77458829f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T12:12:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.13-beta.0.18+d47579bec53f66", GitCommit:"d47579bec53f6642be3078179a0f413802d8b9ab", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-14T08:34:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

[root@gd-dpnsf03 kubelet]# `docker -v`
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

-> When I check the log of kubelet, I find a 500 error,kubelet logs:

```
> I0708 09:45:24.172081   55823 server.go:814] POST /exec/kube-system/etcd-chamc-cluster2-10.128.123.160/etcd?command=sh&input=1&output=1&tty=1: (13.028994ms) 500
> goroutine 375486762 [running]:
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/httplog.(*respLogger).recordStatus(0xc001375730, 0x1f4)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/httplog/httplog.go:204 +0xc8
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/httplog.(*respLogger).WriteHeader(0xc001375730, 0x1f4)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/httplog/httplog.go:183 +0x35
> k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server/streaming.WriteError(0x47f8be0, 0xc0021a6110, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0x0, 0xc0025ebbc9)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server/streaming/errors.go:53 +0x6d
> k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server.(*Server).getExec(0xc00022e6e0, 0xc002410240, 0xc002ce2a20)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go:724 +0x2e6
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*Container).dispatch.func5(0xc002410240, 0xc002ce2a20)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/container.go:272 +0x3e
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*FilterChain).ProcessFilter(0xc0024102d0, 0xc002410240, 0xc002ce2a20)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/filter.go:21 +0x8b
> k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server.(*Server).InstallAuthFilter.func1(0xc002410240, 0xc002ce2a20, 0xc0024102d0)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go:269 +0x52d
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*FilterChain).ProcessFilter(0xc0024102d0, 0xc002410240, 0xc002ce2a20)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/filter.go:19 +0x65
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*Container).dispatch(0xc000c34120, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0xc000be3700)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/container.go:274 +0x7b6
> net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000ff6110, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0xc000be3700)
>         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x44
> net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc000d380c0, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0xc000be3700)
>         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2387 +0x1bd
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.(*Container).ServeHTTP(0xc000c34120, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0xc000be3700)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/emicklei/go-restful/container.go:292 +0x4d
> k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server.(*Server).ServeHTTP(0xc00022e500, 0x4873800, 0xc001375730, 0xc000be3700)
>         /root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/server/server.go:813 +0x124
> net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc001064540, 0x4874140, 0xc000d5aee0, 0xc000be3700)
>         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xa4
> net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc001b56e60, 0x487dd80, 0xc00125afc0)
>         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x875
> created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>         /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2927 +0x38e
>
> logging error output: "container not found (\"etcd\")"
```

The etcds are static pods,pulled up by kubelet through yaml:

```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   annotations:
>     scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
>   creationTimestamp: null
>   labels:
>     cluster: chamc-ctrl
>     component: etcd
>     tier: control-plane
>   name: etcd-chamc-ctrl
>   namespace: kube-system
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - command:
>     - /usr/local/bin/etcd
>     - --advertise-client-urls=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:2379
>     - --auto-compaction-mode=periodic
>     - --auto-compaction-retention=1h
>     - --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
>     - --client-cert-auth=true
>     - --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
>     - --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:2380
>     - --initial-cluster-token=chamc-ctrl-etcd
>     - --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
>     - --listen-client-urls=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379
>     - --listen-peer-urls=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:2380
>     - --logger=zap
>     - --log-outputs=stderr,/var/log/etcd/etcd.log
>     - --name=etcd1
>     - --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
>     - --peer-client-cert-auth=true
>     - --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
>     - --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
>     - --snapshot-count=10000
>     - --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
>     image: xxxxxxxx/library/etcd:v3.4.3
>     imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
>     env:
>     - name: ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER
>       value: "etcd1=https://xx.xx.xx.xx:2380,etcd2=https://xx.xx.xx.161:2380,etcd3=https://xx.xx.xx.162:2380"
>     - name: ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE
>       value: new
>     livenessProbe:
>       exec:
>         command:
>         - /bin/sh
>         - -ec
>         - ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
>           --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
>           get foo
>       failureThreshold: 8
>       initialDelaySeconds: 15
>       timeoutSeconds: 15
>     name: etcd
>     resources:
>       requests:
>         cpu: "500m"
>         memory: "2.5Gi"
>       limits:
>         memory: "2.5Gi"
>     volumeMounts:
>     - mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
>       name: etcd-data
>     - mountPath: /etc/localtime
>       name: localtime
>     - mountPath: /var/log/etcd
>       name: etcd-log
>     - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
>       name: etcd-certs
>   hostNetwork: true
>   priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
>   volumes:
>   - hostPath:
>       path: /data/k8s/etcd-chamc-ctrl
>       type: DirectoryOrCreate
>     name: etcd-data
>   - hostPath:
>       path: /etc/localtime
>     name: localtime
>   - hostPath:
>       path: /data/log/etcd-chamc-ctrl
>     name: etcd-log
>   - hostPath:
>       path: /etc/kubernetes/chamc-ctrl/pki/etcd
>       type: DirectoryOrCreate
>     name: etcd-certs
> status: {}
```

`kubectl describe etcd_pod`:

```
> Name:         etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.160  
> Namespace:    kube-system  
> Node:         10.128.128.160/10.128.128.160  
> Start Time:   Tue, 17 Nov 2020 15:33:41 +0800  
> Labels:       cluster=chamc-cluster2  
>               component=etcd  
>               tier=control-plane  
> Annotations:  kubernetes.io/config.hash: 8ea0def76c8384a384b5f1650dd86cd4  
>               kubernetes.io/config.mirror: 8ea0def76c8384a384b5f1650dd86cd4  
>               kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2020-11-17T15:33:40.684692889+08:00  
>               kubernetes.io/config.source: file  
>               scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod:  
> Status:       Running  
> IP:           10.128.128.160  
> Containers:  
>   etcd:  
>     Container ID:  docker://f9fc1087b9a00ae54ca6f8cb5211a3dfcec40b0d551ccd73e97b2f830ec4f92d  
>     Image:         xxxx/library/etcd:v3.4.3  
>     Image ID:      docker-pullable://xxxx/library/etcd@sha256:3894798fdcc68d408401917bafb6bc98abf557bd474aabf0316f1e0722467a63  
>     Port:          <none>  
>     Host Port:     <none>  
>     Command:  
>       /usr/local/bin/etcd  
>       --advertise-client-urls=https://10.128.128.160:2379  
>       --auto-compaction-mode=periodic  
>       --auto-compaction-retention=1h  
>       --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt  
>       --client-cert-auth=true  
>       --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd  
>       --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://10.128.128.160:2380  
>       --initial-cluster-token=chamc-cluster2-etcd  
>       --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key  
>       --listen-client-urls=https://10.128.128.160:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379  
>       --listen-peer-urls=https://10.128.128.160:2380  
>       --logger=zap  
>       --log-outputs=stderr,/var/log/etcd/etcd.log  
>       --name=etcd1  
>       --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt  
>       --peer-client-cert-auth=true  
>       --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key  
>       --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt  
>       --snapshot-count=10000  
>       --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt  
>     State:          Running  
>       Started:      Sat, 05 Dec 2020 11:37:25 +0800  
>     Last State:     Terminated  
>       Reason:       Error  
>       Exit Code:    2  
>       Started:      Sat, 05 Dec 2020 11:35:49 +0800  
>       Finished:     Sat, 05 Dec 2020 11:37:25 +0800  
>     Ready:          True  
>     Restart Count:  27  
>     Limits:  
>       memory:  2560Mi  
>     Requests:  
>       cpu:     500m  
>       memory:  2560Mi  
>     Liveness:  exec [/bin/sh -ec ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key get foo] delay=15s timeout=15s period=10s #success=1 #failure=8  
>     Environment:  
>       ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER:        etcd1=https://10.128.128.160:2380,etcd2=https://10.128.128.161:2380,etcd3=https://10.128.128.162:2380  
>       ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE:  new  
>     Mounts:  
>       /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd from etcd-certs (rw)  
>       /etc/localtime from localtime (rw)  
>       /var/lib/etcd from etcd-data (rw)  
>       /var/log/etcd from etcd-log (rw)  
> Conditions:  
>   Type              Status  
>   Initialized       True  
>   Ready             True  
>   ContainersReady   True  
>   PodScheduled      True  
> Volumes:  
>   etcd-data:  
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)  
>     Path:          /data/k8s/etcd-chamc-cluster2  
>     HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate  
>   localtime:  
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)  
>     Path:          /etc/localtime  
>     HostPathType:  
>   etcd-log:  
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)  
>     Path:          /data/log/etcd-chamc-cluster2  
>     HostPathType:  
>   etcd-certs:  
>     Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)  
>     Path:          /etc/kubernetes/chamc-cluster2/pki/etcd  
>     HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate  
> QoS Class:         Burstable  
> Node-Selectors:    <none>  
> Tolerations:       :NoExecute  
> Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. How did you set up your cluster? Which version did you use? Try to run `kubectl logs {{podname}}` for logs and `kubectl describe pod {{podname}}` for detailed description. Please also paste output as text not as the image.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help ,I have append the informations you need after the question ^_^

Comment: how is `kubectl -n kube-system exec etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.160 -- date`

Comment: The result of the command is same as the question ^_^

[root@gd-dvnsfmaster4 kubelet]# kubectl -n kube-system exec etcd-chamc-cluster2-10.128.128.160 -- date –

error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("etcd")

Comment: did you see that pod when sort out pods in kube-system namespace, `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Comment: Yes,they are.As I have mentioned,"There are three pods of etcd,after I restart one of them I can login by 'kubectl exec '"

[root@gd-dvnsfmaster4 kubelet]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep etcd
etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.160                      1/1     Running     14         60m
etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.161                      1/1     Running     15         53m
etcd-chamc-ctrl-10.128.128.162                      1/1     Running     14         226d

Comment: You are using very old, unsupported version of Kubernetes. I have found also probably solution to your problem. It looks like you have a problem with networking. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155479/15407542.

Comment: The network model of my cluster is hostnetwork,so it seems to have nothing to with networking.